# Docker error creating bridge

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, docker

After installing Docker on a Ubuntu 14.04 minimal system with these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install docker.io
ln -sf /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/local/bin/docker
sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io
```

I ran into the following problem while trying to run the docker daemon:

```
# docker -d
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a] +job initserver()
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a.initserver()] Creating server
2014/08/11 09:55:20 Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a] +job init_networkdriver()
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a.init_networkdriver()] creating new bridge for docker0
Error creating bridge: package not installed
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)
Error creating bridge: package not installed
[/var/lib/docker|3225259a] -job initserver() = ERR (1)
2014/08/11 09:55:20 Error creating bridge: package not installed
```

I've read that this error might correspond to the kernel.

`uname -r` gives me `3.13.0-042stab092.2`.

Answer (score 1):

This means you don't have the `bridge` kernel module loaded. On most machines, loading the module looks like this:

```
sudo modprobe bridge
```